# I want to change price depending on checkboxes ticked. How to remove if statement from onSubmit()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web, mern

I want the users to select items form checkbox and submit a numerical price according to the items selected. I have tried it here using if statement. How to do this efficiently??
i had tried to map the states using this.state.map() but its not working also.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      check1: false,
      check2: false,
      check3: false,
      check4: false,
    };
    this.onCheckChange = this.onCheckChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onCheckChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.checked,
    });
  }

//**************i want to change this ****************

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var price = 0;
    if (this.state.check1 === true) {
      price = price + 10;
    }
    if (this.state.check2 === true) {
      price = price + 20;
    }
    if (this.state.check3 === true) {
      price = price + 30;
    }
    if (this.state.check4 === true) {
      price = price + 40;
    }
    console.log(price);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          checkboxes are placed
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SellComponent;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking to reduce redundancy (*and assuming the pattern holds**) then a reduction over the array of state values could work.

Array::map returns a *new* array of equal length, it's a 1-1 relationship. The callback used with array::map *should also be a **pure function***, meaning it has ***zero*** side-effects. Contrast this with array::reduce, which uses a pure function callback and returns a single value, i.e. `price`, or array::forEach that *can* have side-effects in the callback, i.e. it can update an external `price`, but is a void return.

* Summation pattern:

```
price = SUM[v, i=0_n] v_i ? (i + 1) * 10) : 0
```

Price computation using array::reduce

```
const computePrice = values =>
  values.reduce((price, value, index) => price + (value ? (index + 1) * 10 : 0), 0);
```

Usage:

```
onSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const price = computePrice(Object.values(this.state));
  console.log(price);
}
```

```js
const computePrice = values =>
  values.reduce((price, value, i) => price + (value ? (i + 1) * 10 : 0), 0);

const generalizedData = [
  [false], // 0
  [true], // 10
  [false, true], // 20
  [false, true, true], // 50
  [true, false, true, false], // 40
  [true, true, true, true, true], // 150
  [true, true, false, true, true, false, true, false], // 190
];

generalizedData.forEach(state => console.log('price', computePrice(state)));
```

Price computation using array::forEach

```
const computePrice = values => {
  let price = 0;
  values.forEach((value, i) => {
    price += value ? (i + 1) * 10 : 0;
  });
  return price;
};
```

Usage: *Same as before*

```js
const computePrice = values => {
  let price = 0;
  values.forEach((value, i) => {
    price += value ? (i + 1) * 10 : 0;
  });
  return price;
};

const generalizedData = [
  [false], // 0
  [true], // 10
  [false, true], // 20
  [false, true, true], // 50
  [true, false, true, false], // 40
  [true, true, true, true, true], // 150
  [true, true, false, true, true, false, true, false], // 190
];

generalizedData.forEach(state => console.log('price', computePrice(state)));
```

Comment: Why can't I do ```this.states.map( )``` @drewreese

Comment: @VijayPD Array::map returns a new array of equal length, it's a 1-1 relationship. The callback used with array::map should also be a pure function, meaning it has ***zero*** side-effects. You are just wanting to iterate over your data and compute a single value. You *could* also do this with array::forEach, where you declare `let price = 0;` first then forEach and sum up price. Array::reduce simply declares this initial value in the second parameter.

Comment: @VijayPD I updated answer with array:forEach example, notice it is a bit more verbose than array::reduce. You *could* use array::map and do the same computation, the language allows for it, but you really shouldn't use map as conceptually it is different than forEach.